# Override base class return type

Tags: c++, sdl

I've got a Button class, like this:

```
class Button {    
    protected:
        SDL_Rect box;

    public:
        Button(string id, int x, int y, int w, int h);
        ~Button();
        virtual void handleEvent(SDL_Event event);
};
```

And I've got a special kind of Button, MyButton:

```
class MyButton : public Button {    
    public:
        MyButton(string id, int x, int y, int w, int h);
        ~MyButton();
        void handleEvent(SDL_Event event);          
};
```

The thing is, I need the `MyButton::handleEvent()` method to return `int` instead of `void`. What is the most elegant way to do this?

EDIT: the reason I need this is because I need to know when `MyButton` was pressed in order to do some other things in other classes.

Comment: If you need a function with a different signature, then you are missing the semantics of inheritance. Just call it a different name.

Comment: And what do I do with the original signature? I just leave it empty?

Comment: It is not necessary to override it, if you dont declare it, the parent's class method will be used instead.  Maybe you can give a little bit of context of what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all with the notion of inheritance `MyButton` is an instance of `Button`. What this means is that you already have a `handleEvent` method defined in `MyButton` and we cannot have to methods with the same name and with two different return types.

This means that if you want to have a method that returns an integer you can `overload` your `handleEvent` method in `MyButton` with an integer reference parameter and you can set its value in the reference.

```
class MyButton : public Button {    
    public:
        MyButton(string id, int x, int y, int w, int h);
        ~MyButton();
        void handleEvent(SDL_Event event, int& out_param);          
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something but it is ugly:

mybutton.h

```
class MyButton : public Button {
    protected:
        SDL_Rect box;

    public:
        MyButton(string id, int x, int y, int w, int h);
        ~MyButton();
        void handleEvent(SDL_Event event);
        int handleEvent_int(SDL_Event event);
};
```

mybutton.cpp

```
#include "mybutton.h"
void MyButton::handleEvent(SDL_Event event) {
    this->handleEvent_int(event);
}

int MyButton::handleEvent_int(SDL_Event event) {
    //Override it here but with return.
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Button* button=new MyButton();
    button->handleEvent(...);
    MyButton* myButton=(MyButton*)button;
    int result=myButton->handleEvent_int(...);
}
```

You create a whole new function that returns int, call it with different name.
Override the virtual function with this without return it's value.